# Estimating parameter of conitnuous uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation

A moderator secretly adjusts a parameter $\theta>0$ of a machine that generates indepently random numbers from the intervall $[0,\theta]$. We produce $5$ random numbers with the machine and try to estimate $\theta$.

Now, our professor says that it is fair to assume that the generated random numbers obey a continuous uniform distribution, $\mathcal{U}_{[0,\theta]}$, and she sets up the statistical model
$$
\left([0,\infty[^5,~~\mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty[}^5,~~\mathcal{U}_{[0,\theta]}^5\right).
$$
However, I don't understand how this makes sense. If we evaluate the probability of a certain sample, say $(1,1,1,1,1)$ its probability is obviously $0$. If we use the probability measure from above it only provides the probability of getting a sample such that each number is $\leq 1$. So I dont quite understand how this probability measure can be used to estimate $\theta$?

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Your first observation $X_1 \sim \mathcal{U}_{[0,\theta]}$ has a density $\frac1\theta \mathbb I_{[0 \le X_1\le \theta]}$, and the observations are presumably iid, so you can find the joint density for $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5)$. This is a density rather than a probability, so you are correct that any particular set of observations has probability $0$, as with any continuous random variable, but you still have a non-zero density or likelihood when all the observations are between $0$ and $\theta$, and a non-zero CDF.